# Angular 5 will not run more than one method on ngOnInit?

Tags: node.js, angular

I have attached a screenshot of what I am trying to do.  This is so basic yet so frustrating.  I have to run a data parse after retrieving the array of objects from the first method being called but I can't add my method to the one inside ngOnInit or directly after it inside ngOnInit. Either way the method just simply doesn't run. Any ideas?
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqtlR.png)

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getSiteContent(this.route.snapshot.params['id']);

    //Doesnt work
    this.addUpdatedPages();
  }

//in use
getSiteContent(id) {

    this.http.get('/site-content/'+id).subscribe(data => {
      this.siteContent = data;

    });

    //Doesn't show..
    console.log('End of getSiteContent');

}

addUpdatedPages(){

  //Doesn't show
  console.log('Adding pages...');

  for (var i = 0; i < this.siteContent.length; i++) {

    this.checkNull(this.siteContent[i].SiteID, this.siteContent[i].SitePageID);
    console.log(this.nullCheck[0].SiteID);

    if (this.nullCheck.length > 0) {
      this.siteContent[i].SitePageContent = this.nullCheck[0].SitePageContent;
    }

} 
}
```

Comment: Make sure the `getSiteContent` method is not stalling. Have you verified this? Is it doing something that takes really long and is synchronous, which makes it wait before calling any other code? There is no reason that `ngOnInit` would only call one function... it must go to the end of that function and return to move on to any other code, as JavaScript is synchronous and only uses one execution process.

Comment: Try 2 things. First remove the number from the function so just this.test(). Also just try a console.log("test") instead of an alert as they're not always reliable. Other than that I can't see anything else wrong with it.

Comment: Please post the code as text, not as an image.

Comment: getSiteContent takes a little to load but when it finishes then I can modify the data however I want from my form.  I am trying to modify it before it hits the form.

Comment: Added console.log at inside the first method being called in place of the method I added in and the message wont show up in console.  Maybe the method is hanging for some reason even though it grabbed the data?

Answer (score 0):

Everything points to an unhandled exception when you call `this.http.get`. You should check your browsers console, that would show it if there was one. One likely reason is that `http` was not injected or is undefined.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getSiteContent(this.route.snapshot.params['id']);

    // if the above throws an exception anything below would not be called
    this.addUpdatedPages();
}

getSiteContent(id) {
    this.http.get('/site-content/'+id).subscribe(data => {
      this.siteContent = data;
    });

    // If the call above to this.http.get throws an exception the code below would not be called
    console.log('End of getSiteContent');
}
```

---

That being said the method `addUpdatedPages` should be called in the `subscribe` of the `http.get` because you want it to occur *after* the data base been retrieved. Modify the `getSiteContent` so that the line is moved into the callback for the observable's `subscribe` call.

```
this.http.get('/site-content/'+id).subscribe(data => {
  this.siteContent = data;
  this.addUpdatedPages();
});
```